# Android Notification Listener

Tags: android, node.js, android-notification, listener

Посоветуйте пожалуйста node.js фреймворк для прослушивания уведомлений на моём андроид устройстве.

Что я хочу сделать:
Как только мне на андроид устройство приходит уведомление допустим от того же телеграма - я пошлю POST запрос с помощью REST.api на своё http приложение (тоже написанное на ноде) и отображу уведомление на своём пк.

Возможно уже есть хорошее готовое решение, буду рад узнать о нём)

P.S. Я знаю, что на андроид лучше писать на java, а на пк лучше использовать c++, однако я хочу использовать node.js

! Дополнение: 
Есть airdroid, который может транслировать уведомления, а значит в принципе если дать разрешение этому приложению, то можно реализовать эту фичу, разве нет?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что у вас нет опыта разработки под андроид? я могу представить как можно запустить веб-сервер с node.js на телефоне, но слабо верю, что есть готовое решение, позволяющее перехватывать события. Придется писать свое приложение, запускающее сервер и передающее ему все перехваченные оповещения. Все это запихнуть в сервис, чтобы работало в фоне... Не самая простая задачка для знакомства с андроид. Перехватчик на "нативном" андроиде будет куда проще сделать

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже уже понимаю, что нода не лучший вариант для этого. Вы сказали про нативность, каким образом это можно сделать? Да, опыта под андроид разработку нет от слова - "совсем".

Comment: Под нативом я имел ввиду java или kotlin с android-sdk и минимумом сторонних фреймворков/библиотек. Пример службы с перехватом уведомлений: https://github.com/Chagall/notification-listener-service-example и слать информацию о перехваченных уведомлениях на некоторый веб-сервер уже на привычном вам node.js, например. Делать это можно кучей спообов, пожалуй библиотека retrofit достаточно проста с точки зрения кода, с хорошим знанием http без проблем разберетесь, думаю

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду ознакамливаться!